# Is it possible to apply a generic function over tuple elements?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have found a for_each loop for tuples which just iterates over the elements and passes them into a function.

```
namespace std {
  template<int I, class Tuple, typename F> struct for_each_impl {
    static void for_each(const Tuple& t, F f) {
      for_each_impl<I - 1, Tuple, F>::for_each(t, f);
      f(get<I>(t));
    }
  };
  template<class Tuple, typename F> struct for_each_impl<0, Tuple, F> {
    static void for_each(const Tuple& t, F f) {
      f(get<0>(t));
    }
  };
  template<class Tuple, typename F>
  void for_each(const Tuple& t, F f) {
    for_each_impl<tuple_size<Tuple>::value - 1, Tuple, F>::for_each(t, f);
  }
}
```

.

```
auto t = std::make_tuple(Foo(),Bar(),Baz());
std::for_each(t,[](???){});
```

Would it be possible to have a generic function like this?

```
std::for_each(t,[](T &&t){t.foo();});
```

In the end I just want to have something that works with every tuple.

```
std::get<0>(t).foo();
std::get<1>(t).foo();
std::get<2>(t).foo();
...
```

Maybe this would be easier with macros?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) you can use a *generic lambda expression*:

```
for_each(t, [] (auto&& t) { std::forward<decltype(t)>(t).foo(); });
```

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you can declare your own *functor*:

```
struct Lambda
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T&& t) const { std::forward<T>(t).foo(); }
};

for_each(t, Lambda{});
```

or if, instead, you would like to apply a different function depending on the tuple element's type currently being processed, then once again a custom functor is the way to go:

```
struct Lambda
{
    void operator()(const Foo& foo) const { foo.foo(); }
    void operator()(const Bar& bar) const { bar.bar(); }
    void operator()(const Baz& baz) const { baz.baz(); }
};

for_each(t, Lambda{});
```

And as a side note: do not define functions inside the `std` namespace.